# How to drag and drop an ImageView onto another ImageView?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, listener, actionlistener

I'm rather new to Android but have successfully managed a few bits and pieces.

What I'm trying to achieve right now is a simple drag and drop activity, that allows the user:

- To drag and drop a shape "ImageView" onto another shape "ImageView".
- If the images:
  matches - it should replace the image it was dropped on,
  if not - it should snap back to where it was.

I know this means creating an if/else block in my drop event but after thumbing few many tutorials I couldn't piece together what I needed. And I currently don't have enough Java knowledge to pull this off.

Currently I have a layout which holds 6 ImageViews, where 3 are static and 3 can be moved on the screen and placed on the layout but not on the ImageViews.

I think this is because I've designed the DragListener to my layout and not to the ImageViews, but I'm a little lost, can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
DragandDrop.java    

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.Activity;

public class DragandDrop extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draganddrop);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.top_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.bottom_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        from.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout to = (LinearLayout) v;
        to.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

draganddrop.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".draganddrop"
android:background="@drawable/dragshapes"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/dropLayout">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/square_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/squareImage1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragsquare1" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/circleImage1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragcircle1" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/triangle_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/triangleImage1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragtriangle1" />



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/square_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/squareImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragsquare" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/circleImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragcircle" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/triangle_text_content"
        android:id="@+id/triangleImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dragtriangle" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check out the tutorial which might help you. http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/11/simple-drag-drop-views-on-screen-in.html Also check for more http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/drag-and-drop-functionality-to-move.html

Comment: thank you but there just massive lines of code, although i can interpret alot of it it doesnt explain how to implement it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove setting drag listeners for the containers

```
findViewById(R.id.top_container).setOnDragListener(this);  //Remove this
findViewById(R.id.bottom_container).setOnDragListener(this);  //Remove this
```

- Check whether the dragged image view matches with your dropped view.
  If they are matching:

  - Set the dropped ImageView's background to that of the dragged one.
    (Other dimensions are same as per your xml file)

Sample code:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        
        if (view.getId()==R.id.squareImage1 && v.getId()==R.id.squareImage) {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(@drawable/dragsquare1);  //TODO: Change this pseudo code.
            return true;
        
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.circleImage1 && v.getId()==R.id.circleImage) {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(@drawable/dragcircle1);  //TODO: Change this pseudo code.
            return true;

        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.triangleImage1 && v.getId()==R.id.triangleImage) {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(@drawable/dragtriangle1);  //TODO: Change this pseudo code.
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you...
Merry Christmas

Comment: Merry christmas indeed thank you very much :-) but its actually still giving me errors on the Ids saying cannot resolve symbol getId and is also saying its got some syntax errors unexpected semi colons missing ) missing; amongst others. @nikvs

Comment: oops i forgot "()" in getId.Sorry