# drag and drop image on an image view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-imageview

hi i today asked this question [how to drag and drop a image onto a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759600/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-image-onto-a-image/20760138?noredirect=1#20760138) and somebody happily gave me an answer that really looks like it should work, yet putting it into my code and taking out what i was told, still gives me errors

cannot resolve symbol `getId` and also tells me there are syntax errors

can anybody help (and maybe explain a little please)

my updated code is as follows, forever thankful for any and all help

.Java   (UPDTAED)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;

public class DragandDrop extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draganddrop);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        if(view.getId()==R.id.squareImage && v.getId()==R.id.squareImage1)
        {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(R.drawable.dragsquare);
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.circleImage1 && v.getId()==R.id.circleImage){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(R.drawable.dragcircle);
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.triangleImage1 && v.getId()==R.id.triangleImage){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackground(R.drawable.dragtriangle);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
return true;
}
}
```

here is my updated logcat

```
Information:3 errors
Information:Compilation completed with 13 errors and 0 warnings in 3 min 40 sec
Information:13 errors
Information:0 warnings
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SocialStories2:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
C:\Users\dawne  allen\AndroidStudioProjects\SocialStories2Project\
SocialStories2\src\main\java\com\martinsapp\socialstories\DragandDrop.java
Error:Error:line (46)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be     
applied to given types;
Error:Error:line (46)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be   applied to given types;

required: Drawable
Error:Error:line (46)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be  applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int
Error:Error:line (46)Gradle: error: method 
setBackground in class View cannot be applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Drawable by 
method invocation  conversion
Error:Error:line (51)Gradle: error: method setBackground in  
class View cannot be  applied to given types;
Error:Error:line (51)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be applied to given types;

required: Drawable
Error:Error:line (51)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be  applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int
    Error:Error:line (51)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be   
applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Drawable by 
method invocation     conversion
Error:Error:line (56)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be  applied to given types;
Error:Error:line (56)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be   applied to given types;

required: Drawable
Error:Error:line (56)Gradle: error: method setBackground in 
class View cannot be      applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int
Error:Error:line (56)Gradle: error: method setBackground 
in class View cannot be    applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Drawable 
by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getId` is a method name, so it should be invoked with `()`

you should do

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.squareImage && v.getId()==R.id.squareImage1)
```

if there are other syntax errors please post your `logcat`.

Comment: hi thank you very much @gaurav5430 your answer solved 90% of my issue but i am still receiving syntax errors ive updated the original post with my logcat but again thank you very much

Comment: @martinseal1987 have you made these changes in all the getId() ? can you post the updated code now

Comment: @martinseal1987 change your @drawable/dragsquare to R.drawable.dragsquare ,etc

Comment: i changed my code to your suggestion and it seems i still have errors it now says setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)in view cannot be applied to (int) ive updated the code and logcat to reflect this above android studio prompted me to add another return value

Comment: try changing it to setBackgroundResource, i cant see your updated code

Comment: Sorry should be there now its working thank you and I added a reset button :-)